# (SQL Server) Service Broker and Failover Cluster Instance

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, failovercluster

Regarding a datawarehouse-like project, I am studying combination of SQL Server Service Broker in front of SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance, both hosted on a Windows Server Failover Cluster-ed double-node box.

My questions:

1. Is it really possible? :)
2. How will database service broker have to be declared to be compatible with a SQL FCI automatic failover behavior?
3. Has the service broker to be declared on both "instance" nodes to be seen whichever the active node is?
4. In case I add a third read-only node to turn the thing into an Availability Group based on WSFC, how to make service broker and AG listener work together properly?

If I'm any wrong, please correct. Thanks **a lot** for sharing your expertise anyway.

Jean-Yves

P.S: I know about both Change Data Capture/Change Tracking features to fit DWH needs, but I'd like to stick to SSB ;)

Comment: Never did that but SB is supported on clustered servers as indicated in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171578(v=sql.105).aspx, look at the [Reliable delivery] section.

Comment: I have not tried SB in a clustered instance, but since the whole instance fails over to the other node you should have no problem. The broker IDs for the databases will match and the configurations will be there. The only thing I can think of is to use the cluster name in your routes, not individual node names.

Comment: @kirchner hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like specifying the virtual network name in the route shall do the trick. I am still a bit confused regarding the AG option, will see. 
Thanks jyao/kirchner and Remus for the support